# Test URL quickly without using GetResponse()

Tags: c#, .net, url

In C# I need to test a URL quickly without actually waiting for a full response. Is there a way to just drop out if there was a response or some other way of testing the URL quickly?

I am retrieving large amounts of data from a website and just need to make sure that it exists beforehand.

This is what I have now:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(arg.Sources[i]);
 try
 {
  request.GetResponse();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {                            
      CMD("HTML Connection Fail");
      return false;
 }
 CMD("Connection Successful");
```

Waiting for the response takes a long time though so is there something I can replace it with?

So is there some other way to test the URL connection without waiting for a full response from the server?

Website is change returnall to false if you don't want your browser to possibly crash: "www.odata.charities.govt.nz/GrpOrgLatestReturns?$filter=RegistrationStatus%20eq%20%27Registered%27&$returnall=true&$format=csv%22"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request.Method = "HEAD"` if you don't need to receive the content and need to verify correctness of the URL. This may not work with some servers however.

Comment: I keep getting a '501 Not Implemented' Error. The head of the site is '<head>' meaning its empty is that what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the method to `HEAD`.  The server should only return headers without the body, so it should return quickly.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(arg.Sources[i]);
try
{
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    request.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                            
    CMD("HTML Connection Fail");
    return false;
}
CMD("Connection Successful");
```

Answer (score 1):

Would pinging the URL be a solution for you?  Check out the Ping Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send ("www.contoso.com");

if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
     // Looks good
}
else
{
    // Doesn't exist or is down
}
```

Comment: Ping tells me the following website does not exist which trust me id does: "http://www.odata.charities.govt.nz/GrpOrgLatestReturns?$filter=RegistrationStatus%20eq%20%27Registered%27&$returnall=true&$format=csv"

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`BeginGetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) method on the request which returns immediately without blocking the caller thread. You will need to provide a callback function that will be invoked once the client receives some response from the server. But of course this callback will be invoked on a different thread later than the actual call to the BeginGetResponse method. It is inside this callback that you could put your tr/catch statement and parse the actual response from the server if you needed to.